# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

Hi I have a DF i am trying to send to HTML table. For sample, here is the one and only row I have:

```
mdf = [('2007291533_946908J.70J.908J-06.FPP.FMGN512.rSBDl5kn9o4R4wP7dtmissbinallerrors.log', 'K946', 'nabcs', '027', 'ERROR: 2007291533_946908J.70J.908J-06.FPP.FMGN512.rSBDl5kn9o4R4wP7dtmissbinallerrors.loghas bad formatting because it has No product offset', 'C:\\Users\\error_dir\\2007291533_946908J.70J.908J-06.FPP.FMGN512.rSBDl5kn9o4R4wP7dtmissbinallerrors.log') ]
```

As you can see there are six items in the tuple

But when I try to unpack it in this:

```
for tup in mdf:
        for filename, lot, lot_owner, holder, error, location in tup:
            hlist.append(f"\n<tr><td>{filename}</td><td>{lot}</td><td>{lot_owner}</td><td>{holder}</td><td>{error}</td><td>{location}</td></tr>\n")
```

I get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6)

How is this possible when I have 6 items in the second for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are looping in the tuple.

```
for item in tup:
    print(item)
```

Each iteration of item in tuple will give you each content of the tuple. Each item is going to be only one value (first iteration is going to be your filename, the second will be lot, etc). You cannot unpack 6 values from filename.

Try

```
for filename, lot, lot_owner, holder, error, location in mdf:
        hlist.append(f"\n<tr><td>{filename}</td><td>{lot}</td><td>{lot_owner}</td><td>{holder}</td><td>{error}</td><td>{location}</td></tr>\n")
```

Comment: Wait but each item in mdf is a tuple. Why would you unpack the tuple on the mdf level (list level)

Comment: Guess you are giving the same answer as mine. Check that the OP is unpacking ```holder``` and using ```wafer```, this won't work

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edited the OP to say holder.It should be holder and that is not the issue though. @antonioplacerda

Comment: @antonioplacerda Slightly different. I suggest the OP to eliminate the second for-loop for each tup. Yeah wafer needs to be changed to holder.

Comment: Yes, I know. If you have a list of tuples and you iterate over it, each element is a tuple, so each element is what you should unpack. If you make a second for loop then you are iterating over the tuple, so each element of the second loop is the element of the tuple, that's why you get a ValueError

Comment: Ah yeah we are talking about the same thing then if you meant the ```tup```as the ```mdf````in the OP's statement

Comment: @andondraif yes, I edited it... Guess it was the wrong answer with ```tup``` instead of ```mdf````

Comment: @edo101 because if you do ```for tup in mdf```, each tup will be a tuple that consists of 6 items. If you do ```for a, b, c, d, e, f in mdf```, each iter will already unpack all the 6 contents of the tup.

Comment: Ah so unpacking is literally taking out the elements of whatever you are iterating. in this case I am iterating through each tuple in mdf and unpacking the elements? I viewed it as similar to pure iteration and printing the elements in each iterable

Comment: Still sctratching my head a little but I sorta get it, thanks! @andondraif

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of tuples, you are unpacking it at the wrong level, I guess.

Isn't this what you need?

```py
for filename, lot, lot_owner, holder, error, location in mdf:
    hlist.append(f"\n<tr><td>{filename}</td><td>{lot}</td><td>{lot_owner}</td><td>{holder}</td><td>{error}</td><td>{location}</td></tr>\n")
```

Comment: But how am I unpacking it at the wrong level? The first level is the top view of each tuple which is why i said for tup in mdf. Then the second level is extracting the values from the tuple so I unpacked it. Why is this wrong?

Comment: you need a single for loop. The second one will iterate over the tuple and that's why you can't unpack it.

Comment: Still sctratching my head a little but I sorta get it, thanks!

Comment: try not unpacking and printing on the second loop, like this: ```for tup in mdf: for t in tup: print(t)``` maybe you can grasp it!

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you simply need to unpack tuple. I think you're going a bit too complicated and I'm not sure why no one has suggested it yet, but the simplest way to do it will be:

```
for tup in mdf:
    filename, lot, lot_owner, holder, error, location = tup
    hlist.append(f"\n<tr><td>{filename}</td><td>{lot}</td><td>{lot_owner}</td><td>{holder}</td><td>{error}</td><td>{location}</td></tr>\n")
```

There's really no need for a second `for` loop.

Comment: Having no second for-loop is already suggested by the 2 other answers

Comment: But unpacking a tuple with simple assignment expression wasn't.

Comment: I think if we talk about simplicity, it depends on the reader. Having 2 lines are simple enough for me as I do not prefer to add one more line for assignment. But preference is subjective

Comment: I like your solution, but I have to honestly say that it can be a bit confusing to read. It's very clear what it does in the example provided where we have a single tuple with 6 values in a list. But if we have multiple tuples, your solution still works, but it can be confusing (and it certainly was confusing to me) how exactly these values are assigned in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks @pavel for the nugget. Makes it easier to visualize what's going on